# jquery(primefaces) is not included after redirect

Tags: jquery, jsf, redirect, primefaces, defined

I'm new to primefaces and try to realize a simple web-app with jsf. In this app I have a login.xhtml where a user can enter a name and his password. If login is successfull, my LoginBean class redirects him to another page called index.xhtml in the folder basicSites. 
While on login.xhtml everything works fine, on index.xhtml occured an error. After the redirect to this site i only see a white site, and the browser console told me that there was a reference error, because jQuery is not defined. I researched through many other articles that have had a similar problem, but my problem isnt still solved.

Here are some code snippets for better understanding.

login.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <title>Zugangsverwaltung | Login</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/default.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/syntax.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" href="#{request.contextPath}/scripts.js"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#logoutLink').fadeOut();
        });
        function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) { 
            if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {  
                jQuery('#dialog').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
            } else {  
                dlg.hide();  
                jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut(0); 
                jQuery('#logoutLink').fadeIn();
            }  

        } </script>
```

LoginBean.java

```
public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = null;
    boolean loggedIn = false;

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        request.login(username, password);
        loggedIn = true;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Willkommen", username);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("global", msg);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        loggedIn = false;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login fehlgeschlagen!", "Invalid credentials");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("local", msg);
    }

    try {
        if (loggedIn) {
            ExternalContext ectx = ctx.getExternalContext();
            ectx.redirect(request.getContextPath() + "/basicSites/index.xhtml");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("LoginBean - login: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

And at least the index.xhtml, where the error occurs:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Zugriffsverwaltung | Backend</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/default.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/syntax.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" href="#{request.contextPath}/scripts.js" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function () { <!-- Here: JQuery is not definded --> 
            jQuery('#logoutLink').fadeOut();
        });</script>

    <p:layout fullPage="true" >
        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center"> <!-- ... -->
```

I hope anyone have an idea what to do now ;) I'm appreciate for every hint that helps me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` to your page

If the above wont help :

You can also add

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

To your `<h:head>` , that should include the jQuery bundled with primefacs

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D I already have the xmlns:p...in my code, but it seems as if I forget it to post...sorry ^^ I've seen the manual include with the h:outputScript also in many other articles, and tried it of course, but it still wont work for me :((

Comment: @BlaBlub try placing your code into js file and include it... (move your js code into seperate .js file)

Comment: Ah, good idea :D After doing this I dont get the error in the browser console. But I still didnt see anything... -.- Is it possible that the complete primefaces ressources are lost by the redirect? Because when I replace the complete <p:layout> ... </p:layout> block from the index.xhtml with an simple htmltextline, for example <b>Hello World</b> I could see it after the redirect...the xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  is included in my file...

Comment: what do you see? if you view source code of the page , do you see the raw `<p:layout>` tags ? if so you haven't included the primefaces jar in your class path... add it - drop it into your lib folder...

Comment: I already had have included the jar in the lib folder and added it to my class path ;-) Fortunately I found the error located in my faces-config and now it works fine! Thanks for your help :)